# How to do int input validation with a float?

Tags: validation, input, visual-c++, floating-point, integer

I have set up this project right as like some practice with C++ and this code runs perfectly except for this one bug with floats being input into an int variable which, the way the program runs, should count the float as an error and jump into my while loop.

The while loops actually catch the error, but it shoves it into the next loop counting it as an error, but also just pulling the float as an int by pulling the first numbers in front of the decimal point as the int. I was wondering if there is any way to get this to not happen.

This would be the output or should be the image of what the console displayed when entering the value of float for an int of my project:

[image: This would be the output or should be the image of what the console displayed when entering the value of float for an int of my project]

Code:

```
void TicketManager::ticketRequest()
{
    //Check the array if the seats are available. If so, output the list of seats, price per seat & total charge. If not, return to menu. 

    bool isAvaliable = true;
    int numOfSeats;
    int rowNum;
    int startingSeat;

    cout << "Ticket Request\n";
    cout << setw(15) << setfill('-') << "\n";
    cout << "Enter number of seats desired: ";

    /* While loop for if the num of seats is not a digit and not inside the max and the min of set parameters.*/
    while (!(cin >> numOfSeats && (numOfSeats - trunc(numOfSeats) == 0) && (numOfSeats <= 30) && (numOfSeats > 0)))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: You must enter a number between 1-30.\nPlease re-enter number of seats desired: ";
        //Prevents an infinite loop
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }


    cout << "Enter the desired row number: ";

    /* While loop for if the row of seats is not a digit and not greater than or equal to 0
       and not less than or equal to 15*/
    while (!(cin >> rowNum && (rowNum <= 15) && (rowNum > 0)))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: You must enter a number between 1-15.\nPlease re-enter number the desired row number: ";

        //Prevents an infinite loop
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    
    cout << "Enter the starting seat: ";

    /*This section needed a little more - We needed to verify that the number was between 1-30 
    AND that there were enough seats in the row after the starting number.*/
    while (!(cin >> startingSeat && (startingSeat <= 31 - numOfSeats) && (startingSeat > 0)))
    {
        //Case if startingSeat is outside 1-30
        if(startingSeat > 30 || startingSeat <= 0)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "ERROR: You must enter a number between 1-30. Please re-enter the starting seat: ";

            //Prevents an infinite loop
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        //Case if there were more seats requested than there were seats left in the row (startingSeat > 31 - numOfSeats)
        else if (startingSeat > 31 - numOfSeats)
        {
            char confirmation;

            cout << "You cannot request this starting seat because there aren't enough seats left in this row.\n";
            cout << "Do you want to try again with a different seat? Enter Y or N: ";

            while (!(cin >> confirmation && ((confirmation == 'N' || confirmation == 'n') || (confirmation == 'Y' || confirmation == 'y'))))
            {
                cout << "ERROR: Please enter either a Y for 'yes' or N for 'no'.\n";

                //Prevents an infinite loop
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }

            if (confirmation == 'Y' || confirmation == 'y')
            {
                cout << "Please re-eneter the starting seat: ";
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //Subtracting one to make logic easier later on
    rowNum --;
    startingSeat --;

    cout << "\n";

    
    

    //This is the check to see if the seats are available.
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSeats; i++)
    {
        

        if (seats[rowNum][startingSeat].seatAvailability == '*')
        {
            isAvaliable = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isAvaliable == true)
    {
        //Text outputting all of the seat information.
        cout << "The seats you chose are available!\n";
        cout << "Row Number: " << rowNum + 1 << "\n";

        //This if statement checks to see how many seats the person selected. If it's greater than one, the output changes to reflect this.
        if (numOfSeats > 1) 
        {
            //Code for the seat numbers. +1 is added to represent the real value as opposed to the value of the element
            cout << "Seat Numbers: " << startingSeat + 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < numOfSeats; i++)
            {
                cout << ", " << startingSeat + 1 + i;
            }
            cout << "\n";

            //Code for the seat prices.
            cout << "Each seat in this row costs $" << seats[rowNum][startingSeat].seatPrice << ".\n";
            cout << "The total cost of these seats is $" << (numOfSeats * seats[rowNum][startingSeat].seatPrice) << ".\n";
        }
        //In the case there was one one seat selected, this will run.
        else
        {
            cout << "Seat Number: " << startingSeat + 1;
            cout << "This seat costs $" << seats[rowNum][startingSeat].seatPrice << ".\n";
        }

        //This is to check and see if they want to purchase the tickets. 
        char willTheyPurchase;
        cout << "Would you like to complete this purchase? Enter Y or N: ";
        while (!(cin >> willTheyPurchase && ((willTheyPurchase == 'N' || willTheyPurchase == 'n') || (willTheyPurchase == 'Y' || willTheyPurchase == 'y'))))
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Please enter either a Y for 'yes' or N for 'no'.\n";

            //Prevents an infinite loop
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        if (willTheyPurchase == 'Y' || willTheyPurchase == 'y')
        {
            cout << "\n\n";
            purchase(numOfSeats, rowNum, startingSeat, (numOfSeats * seats[rowNum][startingSeat].seatPrice));
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (isAvaliable == false)
    {
        char tryAgain;
        cout << "One of the seats you selected was not available.\nWould you like to try again? Enter Y or N: ";
        cin >> tryAgain;

        if (tryAgain == 'Y' || tryAgain == 'y')
        {
            ticketRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the ints to floats, but the thing is when doing that it makes the variables for the seats structure I have made (the seats array you see is a structure full with prices and availability in seats) and as you can see with the numOfSeats we have tried the trunc and touched on floor, but when it came to the int value entering a float ignores the numbers after the decimal point and grabs the numbers in front of the decimal point as the int number and since the decimal is being ignored it grabs it, but since it is an error as a float it does go into the input validation loop, but of the next loop and the way we need it is the loop making the float an error and shoving it into the corresponding loops.

I will also add that I am pretty sure I am on the most recent update to Visual Studios.